# How can I access, in the view, all the elements of a table linked to another?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I started using mvc3 recently, I created a test project with two tables with a one to many relationship. Table B contains image links and as a foreign key has the id of the elements of table A. So more images of table B are linked to an entity of table A. What I would like to obtain is a view with all images related to an entity of table A.

I was able to create a controller that views the object.
In the view, I don't know how to get a cycle to view the images in table B

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            ADS ads = db.ADS.Single(a => a.id == id);
            return View(ads);
        }
```

view

with this command I can only get the first image, I would like to get them all.

```
@model AgenziaImmobiliare.Models.ADS

...

@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PHOTO.First().link_photo)
```

I would like to do something like this, but it can't be done

```
@foreach(var photo in model => model.PHOTO)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
@if(Model.PHOTO != null){
    for(int i = 0; i <  model?.PHOTO.Count(); i++){
      @Html.Display($"photo-{i}",model.PHOTO[i].link_photo)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was inspired by your suggestion. Now I can see all the images in this way
`@foreach (var item in Model.PHOTO) {<img class = "d-block w-100" src = "@ Html.DisplayFor (photo => item.link_photo)" alt = "First slide" />}`
But now I have another problem, wanting to use the carousel of boostrap:

`@foreach (var item in Model.PHOTO) { 
 <div class = "carousel-item">
                <img class = "d-block w-100" src = "@ Html.DisplayFor (photo => item.link_photo)" alt = "First slide">`
does not show me the images.